# Can you use SVG on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: svg, html5-canvas

I made a SVG in Gimp to use in my cros platform web project.
I was wondering if it was possible to use SVGs on an HTML5 canvas - just like bitmaps.
Or alternativly: Is there a way to convert my SVG into strokes on the canvas?
I need this for animated vectore graphics in my project.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Did you google it? Fourth result: http://getcontext.net/read/svg-images-on-a-html5-canvas

Comment: YES - I searched trough at least 25 pages. But anyway - thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to simply select your path ( `select > to path` ), then export your selection ( `Export path...` ) and paste generated path to your HTML:

```
<path fill="none" stroke="black"
        d=" YOUR PATH HERE " />
</svg>
```

EDIT:
or - if your svg is large - use it directly from svg file, as posted in comment above